# mute program that I code is not working when I enter a word which ends with m letter

Tags: java, arrays, char

The program have to mute when user input includes "m","a","l" letters side by side. But when I enter a word which ends with "m" word, program doesn't work. I left some pictures about code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class mute 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String enteredmessage;

        System.out.print("Enter the message:");
        enteredmessage = scan.nextLine();

        char[] array = enteredmessage.toCharArray();
        mutecommand(array);
        
        scan.close();
    }
    public static void mutecommand(char[] dizi) {
        for (int i = 0; i < dizi.length; i++) {
            if(dizi[i] == 'm' && dizi[i+1] == 'a' && dizi[i+2]=='l')
            {
                dizi[i]='*';
                dizi[i+1]='*';
                dizi[i+2]='*';
            }
        }

        for (char a : dizi) {
            System.out.print(a);
        }
    }
}
```

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHOFw.png]
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/UP32b.png]

Comment: what exactly are you trying to get, and what are you getting?

Comment: Since you don't only access `dizi[i]` but also `dizi[i+1]` and `dizi[i+2]` you need to stop the iteration of your loop when `i+2` would become bigger than the biggest array index. So instead of `i < dizi.length` as our loop condition, try `(i+2) < dizi.length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the fact, that you are iterating through the array and if you at the last item and do an i + 2 so it's out of the array